# How to manage multiple cell selection of UITableView using single NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my code which handles multiple selection of UITableview Cell properly.

**Now, my question is here I had create two array in which one stores array data and second stores selected data. But, I want to do this using only one array. someone had given me solution that it can be done using KVC (valueForKeyPath) by giving key. But I have no exact idea how to do it.**

If anyone knows please help me.

```
#import "NewTableViewController.h"

@implementation NewTableViewController

@synthesize attTableData ;
@synthesize arrSelectionData ;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.attTableData=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dhosa",@"Kahman",@"Dhokla",@"Handvo",@"chodafadi",@"Muthiya",@"Medu Vada",@"Patra",@"Thepla",@"Fafda",@"Gota",@"gathiya",@"Idali",@"Dalvada",@"Samosa",nil];

    self.arrSelectionData=[NSMutableArray array];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.attTableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    if([self.arrSelectionData containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.attTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([self.arrSelectionData containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.arrSelectionData removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.arrSelectionData addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    //[tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

**Solution ::**

Data in "Recipe List" File

```
[0]{
    Item = Thepla;
    selected = 0;
},
[1]
{
    Item = Gota;
    selected = 0;
},
[2]
{
    Item = Handvo;
    selected = 0;
},
[3]
{
    Item = Idali;
    selected = 0;
},
[4]
{
    Item = Dalvada;
    selected = 0;
},
```

Now My TableViewController

```
#import "NewTableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation NewTableViewController
@synthesize attTableData ;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recipe List" ofType:@"plist"];
    attTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    attTableData = (NSMutableArray *)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFArrayRef)attTableData, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.attTableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UserCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    NSDictionary * dicTemp = [attTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //  NSNumber* attendingObject = [dicTemp objectForKey:@"selected"];
    if([dicTemp objectForKey:@"selected"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    else
    {
         [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }

    cell.lbl.text=[[self.attTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Item"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSMutableDictionary * dic = [attTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSNumber* attendingObject = [dic objectForKey:@"selected"];

    if ([dic objectForKey:@"selected"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])
    {
        [dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"selected"];
    }
    else
    {
        [dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"selected"];
    }
    [attTableData replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dic];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
@end
```

Comment: i think you should use NSMiutableDictionary for fetching the values of the Array element

Comment: can you explain how ?

Comment: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-13%E2%80%93The-TableView have a look at this tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using a single array, instead of doing like this

```
self.attTableData=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dhosa",@"Kahman",@"Dhokla",@"Handvo",@"chodafadi",@"Muthiya",@"Medu Vada",@"Patra",@"Thepla",@"Fafda",@"Gota",@"gathiya",@"Idali",@"Dalvada",@"Samosa",nil];
```

Create a model class for your items

```
//pseudo code
class Item{
  name = "Dhosa"
  selected = false
}
```

So  `attTableData` will be

```
 self.attTableData=[Item1, Item2];
```

Now when you make a selection you can set the `selected` property of the item. In `cellForRow` check this property and set `setAccessoryType`.

Comment: can you explain how could I handle it in tableview delegate method ? If you can, please help me.

Comment: first part is clear? create a model class `Item` with the properties i listed and populate your `attTableData` with those objects

Comment: Actually not properly, If you edit your post with code then I can. Please help me If you can

Comment: I get it. I am going to implement this.